# OSGI - get class name in a bundle

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, karaf

For one of a monitoring project I need to find out the class names available in a OSGI bundle (apache Karaf). I checked in the bundle and bundleContext class, but could not find any relevant methods to get the class names. Please help!!

PS - i can get the list of classes using bundle:class command. But i would like to get from the code.

**EDIT** - It is not 1 bundle for which i need to know, i want to run the code in any karaf environment to find all the bundles and also class names in those bundles.

Comment: Should you just import the bundle package in the code?

Comment: Tk u.. i have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do the same that apache karaf does See the source of the classes command:
https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/bundle/core/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/bundle/command/Classes.java

Comment: I am able to get the class names. I want to find whether the class is a component or not. I tried to find from class annotations. But class annotation always is null. Any clue on how a class can be determined whether it is component or not. i.e has @Component annotations on the class?

Comment: There are gogo commands for scr like scr:list and scr:details in karaf. I think scr also has a service that you can use to query the known components.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion!!